# 5×5 image grid – What are we looking at?

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

> [image]

The final answer is the name of a fictional character.

---

Image credits:
<sub>7: Rama, cc by-sa 2.0 fr | 11: Jonathunder, GFDL 1.2 | 13: Volatus, cc by-sa 3.0 | 15.1: ZngZng, cc by-sa 3.0 | 15.2: Ian Kirk, cc by-sa 2.0 | 16: Antonio Litterio, cc by-sa 3.0 | 20: J. Patrick Fischer, cc by-sa 3.0 | 21: Kneiphof & historicair, cc by-sa 3.0 | 22 & 25.2: Jeff Dahl, cc by-sa 4.0 | 23: Mohandoss Sampath, cc by-sa 3.0 | 24: Liné1, cc by-sa 4.0</sub>

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd wager we are looking at

> a [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus). Naturally. :-)

Start by unscrambling the image:

> Assuming that all the circle segments in the corners and on the sides of the images combine to make single-coloured full circles, there's only one way to assemble the jigsaw puzzle into a 5x5 grid as required by the title:
>  [image]

Then, solve it row by row

> Perpendicular - Pound - Empty set - Jewish (Hebrew) Plus - Dollar
>  Naira - Katakana Yo - [Right Semijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A)) - Gimel - Pilcrow
>  Rho - Scruple - Tshe - Universal quantifier - Vertical Bar
>  Small Eth - Existential quantifier - Small Capital Lambda - Exclamation - Shang
>  Open O - Three - Up Tack - Schwa - Latin Alpha

This is very interesting:

> These all are unicode characters of some kind. Particularly of the kind that look like upside-down letters. Write them down, stand on your head, and read.

Like so: (All polished up with a little help from OP's comments below)

> ```
>  ⟂ £ ∅ ﬩ $
>  ₦ ヨ ⋊ ℷ ¶
>  ρ ℈ ћ ∀ |
>  ð ∃ ᴧ ! 上
>  ɔ 3 ⊥ ə Ɑ
> ```

With a little squinting, it reads

> "Detective played by Ken Stott", [which finally brings us to the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus_(TV_series)).

---

**Appendix:** Full reasoning for the individual images, in the unscrambled order:

1:

> **Pe**<s>e</s>**r** to peer, **pen**, **dic**<s>k</s>, *Ural*, swap r and l to get **ular**

2:

> a **pound** is equal to 453.6 grams.

3.

> A set with no elements is called an **empty set**

4.

> Star of David hints at **Hebrew**; it is the symbol for Judaism. The Hebrew language has an alternative symbol for **plus**.

5.

> **Doll** + upside-down (reversed) Egyptian god *Ra* = **ar**

6.

> Latter part of Rastaf*arian* reversed = **Naira**, the Nigerian monetary unit.

7.

> *Katana* + "ka" in the middle = **katakana**, one of the Japanese writing systems. Half of *Yo-yo* is **yo**, a Japanese syllable.

8.

> Arrow pointing to the **right**, followed by New York T*imes*, reversed, for **semi**, and **join**<s>t</s>.

9.

> An upside-down (reversed) *lemming*, with the letters N and M removed: **g**<s>n</s>**i**<s>m</s>**mel**

10.

> **Pil**l + **Crow**, slightly misspelled.

11.

> **Rh**<s>in</s>**o**

12.

> "E**SC**" minus E plus ruble with a letter exchanged: "**ruple**"

13.

> The Egyptian god *Seth*, with letters scrambled in the order given, to get **"Tshe"**. (Surprisingly, didn't have anything to do with the numbers being an approximation for $1000 \times \pi$)

14.

> **Universal** serial bus, "*quid* pro quo" - d + *ant* in the middle = **quanti**, Semper **fi**, *re*conquista (A historical period on the Iberian peninsula) reversed for **er**

15.

> Quite simply **vertical**ly written word **bar**

16.

> S means **small** when written on a tee shirt, **eth** fits all the empty spaces, creating an English word each time.

17.

> *exit* + S = **exist**, *vial* with the letter swap = **ential**, **quant**<s>um</s> mechanics, w**ifi**, flag of Eritrea, country code **er**.

18.

> Ottawa is the (**small**) **capital** of Canada, **lamb**, Cyrillic word "**da**"

19.

> **Ex** libris, **clam**, **AT**&T, hydrogen **ion**

20.

> Picture of **Shang**hai, with the first character of the city's Chinese name hidden

21.

> **o**, **pen**, **o**

22.

> *tree* with an added *h* gives **three**

23.

> Arrow pointing **up**, **t**<s>r</s>**ack**

24.

> Flag of Germany hints at language, the colour pointed at is black, which is *Schwarz* in German, picking the first 5 of the 7 letters gives **Schwa**.

25.

> *(Original puzzle had an error, which is still visible in the unshuffled image; instead of "Si", it was supposed to read "Sn".)* Map has Los Angeles highlighted for **LA**, Sn is the symbol for the element **tin**, and the letter is of course an **alpha**.

---

Comment: This is the intended answer. Although the "afro" works and produces the correct result, I was in fact thinking about a certain Caribbean culture. The arrow in the rail track picture was meant to just point "up", not at anything in the picture.

Comment: If I'm ever in a "Die Hard" kind of situation, you sir are the one I'll call @Bass

Comment: @PierreArlaud: Yippee-kai-yee, Mister Falcon[!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuQP4d_r_Gs#t=235)

Answer (score 3):

A rearrangement.

> The 25 pieces can be rearranged into 4 groups using the coloured circles
>  as cues, as this crude edit shows.
>  
>  [image]

Where to go from here?

Answer (score 2):

Some partials. Combine with @Weather Vane's answer to put them in the correct order for reading.

If we assume that in the OP they are numbered first row 1-5, second row 6-10, etc., then we have:

1.

> THREE = TREE + H

2.

> EXISTENTIAL = EXIT + S + VIAL (with V = ENT)
>  flag of ERITREA

3.

> NULL or NULL SET or EMPTY?

5.

> ? = Silicon + alpha + LA

6.

> SEMIJOIN = IMES (reversed) + JOINT - T

7.

> ? = KA + KATANA + YO (half of YOYO)

8.

> SETH, STETH, ? = the letters that fill in the blanks are ETH, and there's an S in a T-shirt

11.

> RHO = RHINO - IN

13.

> U = capital (Ottawa) ewe

14.

> QUANTIFIER = U + ANT + QUID - D + FI + ER (RE reversed)

17.

> POUND (453.6 grams is approximately 1 pound)

18.

> SCRUPLE = ESC - E + RUBLE (with B = P)

21.

> PERPENDICULAR = PEER - E + PEN + DICK - K + URAL (with L and R switched)

22.

> TSHE = SETH rearranged to take in order 3142

23.

> TACK = TRACK - R

24.

> EXCLAMATION = EX + CLAM + AT + ION

25.

> DOLLAR = DOLL + AR (god RA upside down)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

Continuing from Weather Vane's observation

> that the squares can be rearranged into four groups if we require that the quarter-circles at some of their corners match up,

in fact

> those four groups fit in a unique way into the original 5x5 square shape. Some of the rebuses are easier to make sense of than others; so far I have the following:
>  perpendicular pound empty-set ??star+?? ??doll??
>  or katakana-yo right-semijoin ??? ??pilcrow??
>  rho scruple ??combination-set?? quantifier vertical-bar
>  seth existential-qualifier capital-lambda exclamation shang
>  ??open-o?? three ??ail?? schwa ??Si-alpha-los-angeles??
>  (Credit to Bass for noticing that it's specifically a *right* semijoin, which I hadn't spotted.)

I haven't given detailed explanations of how the rebuses work because I think they're mostly easy to see once you have the answer, but here are a couple of the subtler ones:

> "schwa" is because we have the *German* flag, we're pointing to its *black* stripe, hence *schwarz* (German for black), and we want *5/7* of this, making *schwa*. "katakana yo" is because "ka" has been inserted into the middle of a katana (plus half a yo-yo). "or" is half an Afro, reversed. I don't actually believe "seth" since it doesn't seem to be the name of a symbol, but the point is that you can insert "eth" into all those gaps. "Shang" is because we have a picture of some towers in Shanghai, plus a gap followed by the "hai" character.

which makes me think that

> each square is leading to a single symbol, something like this:
>  ⟂£∅??
>  ∨彐⋊?¶
>  ρ℈??|
>  ?∃Λ!上
>  ɔ3?Ə?

shoover's answer has some plausible explanations for a few of my gaps, yielding

> ⟂£∅?$
>  ∨彐⋊?¶
>  ρ℈Ћ?|
>  ?∃Λ!上
>  ɔ3⊣Ə?

It isn't entirely clear to me what to do next;

> it looks a little as if something good might happen if we read the whole thing upside down, though. (It looks a little like a word-ladder with only one letter changing at each step, but so far I can't make that work and I think it's probably wrong.) At any rate it's striking how many upside-down-E-like things there are in the second column. Perhaps the "or" symbol is actually meant to be a vertical bar and we're meant to read the pilcrow, even upside down, as a P, in which case that row yields "pixel". I suspect the open-o may be meant to be read as a D, even though to my mind that only works if we don't invert it. It's possible that the fourth row might say "fiver", in which case maybe I can pretend that the second row says "hazel" and there's a Watership Down reference going on. But so far this is all just speculation.

Ah!

> I bet it says DETECTIVE - LIVED BAKER STREET, in which case the answer is SHERLOCK HOLMES. (Credit where due: this did not occur to me until I saw Bass's inspired guess that in the mysterious Los Angeles box "Si" is a typo for "Sn", so that that square contains an "a".) If this is right, then clearly I have entirely the wrong symbol in the middle of the first line (an empty set) since it looks nothing like "re" or "ee".